# Как подправить мобильное меню(показ)?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Привет всем.

В данный момент, когда делаю размер страницы `< 992px` и нажимаю на "Основное Меню", то появляется список подменю. Но, когда мы делаем размер страницы `> 992px`, то меню пропадает. *(из-за slideToggle)*.

Также есть баг, когда ставлю медиа-запрос на `> 992px`, то в обычной версии страницы будут открыты оба меню, хотя должно быть открыто то, что мы нажали в моб. версии

Помогите подправить мобильное меню для адаптивки.

Еще раз, кто не понял: 
1. Должно быть так изначально - prntscr.com/e7uyii Сейчас Основное закрыто. Проверьте jsfiddle.net/m5o8pwrd/21 2. Нужно, чтобы при клике в моб. версии на Второе меню(как сейчас prntscr.com/e7uzb1) в нормальной версии также было открыто Второе меню ( prntscr.com/e7uzx1 ), и также с Основным меню. 3. Присутствует баг анимации: когда я нажимаю на Основное меню в нормальном режиме, но нет слайда вниз, а просто появление списка... И, если я нажму на Второе меню, то анимация Основного меню также будет криво работать.

```js
$(function() {
  $a = $('.side-menu > li > span');
  $showlist = $('.side-menu > li > span + ul');
  $a.on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).next().css('overflow', 'hidden')) {
      $(this).next().slideDown(300);
      $a.not(this).next().slideUp(300);
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".mobile").on('click', function() {
    $(".side-menu").slideToggle(300);
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.sidebar {
  flex: 3;
}
aside a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 30px;
}
.sidebar aside {
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e1e1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
.mobile {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: rgba(33, 32, 32, 0.83);
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.our-menu {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: rgba(33, 32, 32, 0.83);
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
.sub-menu li {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.side-menu li {
  transition: all .3s;
}
.side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.side-menu li:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
.side-menu > li > a,
.side-menu > li > span {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.active {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  ;
}
.main {
  flex: 9;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .our-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block
  }
  .side-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .sidebar aside {
    margin: 20px 0px;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <aside>
      <h3 class="our-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Меню</h3>
      <div class="mobile">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Меню</h3>
      </div>
      <ul class="side-menu">
        <li><span>Основное меню</span>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="1">Холодные закуски</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="2">Горячие закуски</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="3">Первые блюда</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Второе меню</span>
          <ul class="sub-menu invisible">
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="14">Первые блюда</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="15">Вторые блюда</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="16">Сладкие блюда</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus nostrum explicabo rem dolorem vel vero culpa repellat ipsa maiores, optio alias tempora ducimus voluptates et neque unde. Quia necessitatibus, deserunt!</div>
    <div>Vero eius molestias exercitationem non molestiae, sint aspernatur. Quos voluptatum modi vitae minima eos magni quas nesciunt architecto, odio vel explicabo officiis hic, voluptates ut. Repudiandae voluptatum maxime eos consequatur!</div>
    <div>Quasi mollitia illo, aliquid rerum atque ipsum accusantium, maiores nulla, repudiandae quo libero rem. Mollitia dolore, ipsum asperiores praesentium voluptatum, aliquam laudantium magnam nemo, tenetur rerum iusto quo laboriosam ullam.</div>
    <div>Expedita minima accusantium asperiores vel doloremque, unde est nulla dolore debitis dolorem, corrupti eos earum nemo, sunt, quos quidem perferendis. Harum enim praesentium vero quo id tempore, voluptatum aliquid cumque.</div>
    <div>In repellat, vel impedit delectus fugiat eligendi eum expedita aspernatur velit hic provident veniam quaerat nostrum assumenda, id ducimus? Maxime eligendi dolores laboriosam. Molestias eius est dicta eaque in! Et!</div>
    <div>Totam possimus officiis odio necessitatibus, ratione repellendus id nesciunt delectus explicabo, amet inventore quaerat, laborum mollitia earum quos nihil eaque at quisquam suscipit non officia unde. Excepturi dignissimos eaque, facere.</div>
    <div>Fugiat voluptas nam repudiandae sed facere, iste, quae enim cum! Quaerat distinctio sed consequuntur neque dolores, necessitatibus totam animi cum veniam, ad obcaecati assumenda iste tempore, itaque nostrum eius sint!</div>
    <div>Voluptatibus minima inventore consequatur voluptatem dolorem quia illum doloremque ducimus provident veritatis voluptates natus amet assumenda, ullam sequi delectus distinctio eum repudiandae quibusdam quod aspernatur voluptate, culpa itaque dolore.
      Nemo.</div>
    <div>Possimus placeat ipsa asperiores doloribus, totam, unde provident illo, cumque, ut similique dolore iure. At ex explicabo iure officiis numquam eligendi aliquam tempore dolores aut distinctio quibusdam quaerat minima, obcaecati.</div>
    <div>Quia voluptatem sed nam possimus qui ad doloremque quos placeat, sequi laboriosam sunt maiores distinctio repellat laborum, cum labore iste illo vitae. Aut expedita modi, tempora laborum! Neque, nulla, blanditiis.</div>
  </div>
```

Ссылка на стороннем редакторе: [jsfiddle-m5o8pwrd-13](https://jsfiddle.net/m5o8pwrd/13/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил в js **$(window).resize(function()**.

```js
$(function() {
  $a = $('.side-menu > li > span');
  $showlist = $('.side-menu > li > span + ul');
  $a.on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).next().css('overflow', 'hidden')) {
      $(this).next().slideDown(300);
      $a.not(this).next().slideUp(300);
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(".mobile").on('click', function() {
    $(".side-menu").slideToggle(300);
  })
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 992) {
    $('.side-menu').removeAttr('style');
  }
   if ($(window).width() < 992) {
    $('.sub-menu').removeAttr('style');
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.sidebar {
  flex: 3;
}
aside a {
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 30px;
}
.sidebar aside {
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #e2e1e1;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
.mobile {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: rgba(33, 32, 32, 0.83);
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.our-menu {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: rgba(33, 32, 32, 0.83);
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
.sub-menu li {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.side-menu li {
  transition: all .3s;
}
.side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.side-menu li:hover {
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
.side-menu > li > a,
.side-menu > li > span {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.active {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  ;
}
.main {
  flex: 9;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .our-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
    display: block
  }
  .side-menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-container {
    display: block;
  }
  .sidebar aside {
    margin: 20px 0px;
  }
  .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <aside>
      <h3 class="our-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Меню</h3>
      <div class="mobile">
        <h3><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Меню</h3>
      </div>
      <ul class="side-menu">
        <li><span>Основное меню</span>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="1">Холодные закуски</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="2">Горячие закуски</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="3">Первые блюда</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Второе меню</span>
          <ul class="sub-menu invisible">
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="14">Первые блюда</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="15">Вторые блюда</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="sub-list" data="16">Сладкие блюда</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus nostrum explicabo rem dolorem vel vero culpa repellat ipsa maiores, optio alias tempora ducimus voluptates et neque unde. Quia necessitatibus, deserunt!</div>
    <div>Vero eius molestias exercitationem non molestiae, sint aspernatur. Quos voluptatum modi vitae minima eos magni quas nesciunt architecto, odio vel explicabo officiis hic, voluptates ut. Repudiandae voluptatum maxime eos consequatur!</div>
    <div>Quasi mollitia illo, aliquid rerum atque ipsum accusantium, maiores nulla, repudiandae quo libero rem. Mollitia dolore, ipsum asperiores praesentium voluptatum, aliquam laudantium magnam nemo, tenetur rerum iusto quo laboriosam ullam.</div>
    <div>Expedita minima accusantium asperiores vel doloremque, unde est nulla dolore debitis dolorem, corrupti eos earum nemo, sunt, quos quidem perferendis. Harum enim praesentium vero quo id tempore, voluptatum aliquid cumque.</div>
    <div>In repellat, vel impedit delectus fugiat eligendi eum expedita aspernatur velit hic provident veniam quaerat nostrum assumenda, id ducimus? Maxime eligendi dolores laboriosam. Molestias eius est dicta eaque in! Et!</div>
    <div>Totam possimus officiis odio necessitatibus, ratione repellendus id nesciunt delectus explicabo, amet inventore quaerat, laborum mollitia earum quos nihil eaque at quisquam suscipit non officia unde. Excepturi dignissimos eaque, facere.</div>
    <div>Fugiat voluptas nam repudiandae sed facere, iste, quae enim cum! Quaerat distinctio sed consequuntur neque dolores, necessitatibus totam animi cum veniam, ad obcaecati assumenda iste tempore, itaque nostrum eius sint!</div>
    <div>Voluptatibus minima inventore consequatur voluptatem dolorem quia illum doloremque ducimus provident veritatis voluptates natus amet assumenda, ullam sequi delectus distinctio eum repudiandae quibusdam quod aspernatur voluptate, culpa itaque dolore.
      Nemo.</div>
    <div>Possimus placeat ipsa asperiores doloribus, totam, unde provident illo, cumque, ut similique dolore iure. At ex explicabo iure officiis numquam eligendi aliquam tempore dolores aut distinctio quibusdam quaerat minima, obcaecati.</div>
    <div>Quia voluptatem sed nam possimus qui ad doloremque quos placeat, sequi laboriosam sunt maiores distinctio repellat laborum, cum labore iste illo vitae. Aut expedita modi, tempora laborum! Neque, nulla, blanditiis.</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Изначально Основное меню должно быть открыто, а Второе - закрыто. И сейчас есть баг. Если нажать на "Второе меню", то анимация странно себя поведет. Резко свернет Основное. Проверьте

Comment: 1. Должно быть так изначально - http://prntscr.com/e7uyii Сейчас Основное закрыто. Проверьте https://jsfiddle.net/m5o8pwrd/21/
2.  Нужно, чтобы при клике в моб. версии на Второе меню(как сейчас http://prntscr.com/e7uzb1) в нормальной версии также было открыто Второе меню ( http://prntscr.com/e7uzx1 ), и также с Основным меню. 
3. Присутствует баг анимации: когда я нажимаю на Основное меню в нормальном режиме, но нет слайда вниз, а просто появление списка... И, если я нажму на Второе меню, то анимация Основного меню также будет криво работать. 
Теперь поняли?

Comment: Изменил, но есть небольшой баг. Когда я в моб. версии нажимаю на "Второе меню" ( http://prntscr.com/e7voxd), то в десктоп версии открыто сразу 2 меню - http://prntscr.com/e7vpai, хотя должно быть открыто только Второе.

Comment: Что-то тоже самое получается. Только тепрь, при клике на Второе меню в моб. версии открыто Основное меню, а не Второе меню. И хотелось бы, чтобы, если я нажал на декстоп версии на Второе меню, то и в моб.версии также было открыто Второе меню, а Основное - закрыто. Если нажал на Основное меню, то в моб. версии также было открыто Основное меню, а Второе - закрыто.

Comment: Видимо я ошибся, извините пожалуйста) Да, на самом деле должно было быть как на prntscr.com/e7uyii изначально. А так, работает сейчас все хорошо.

Comment: @GilB Ert Все, это самый стабильный вариант. Пусть будет на декстопе всегда такое меню на старте(по крайней мере, в начале вы просили именно такой вид). Комментарии лишние я попрошу модератора удалить. Мне стоит поставить заслуженный плюс, а если вам до конца мое решение не нравится, то отредактируйте свой вопрос еще раз, опишите проблему, возможно кто-нибудь другой ответит.

Comment: Смотрите. Да. Оно изначально как и нужно. Основное меню открыто - http://prntscr.com/e7xhdz. Теперь, когда я перехожу в мобильный вариант и нажимаю на Второе меню, а затем перехожу в декстоп, то Второе меню не открыто, а открыто Основное - http://prntscr.com/e7xi2h. Просто идея в том, что: не важно, в какой версии и открыл какое меню - при переходе с одной версии(моб или декстоп) открытое меню должно быть открытым.

Comment: @GilBErt если что, вы сами можете удалять комментарии. )